# how do i vectorise (automate) plot creation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, printing, facet

edited to include sample data:
[Sample data](http://www.filedropper.com/sample_116)

I have been trying to write code to generate and save multiple plots from a large dataset and have to admit defeat. Would love some help if possible..
i have a df (dat) of 4 years of daily monitoring data (sampling year goes July - June, so Sampling.Year[image] notation is YYYY-YYYY). I would like to export jpgs for each SITENAME, with facet wrap/facet grid so each Sampling.Year is stacked vertically. Individual Sampling.Year plots show timeseries data for the full year (x=DATE, y = Daily.Ave.PAF). End result should be individual jpg files (SITENAME saved in file name) with sampling years stacked but DATE (x axis) aligned. That way we can get a quick snapshot of differences over time.  The string is below and my (probably crappy) code is below that. The code is exporting plots just fine, but the data seems to be mixed up - i.e. where a SITENAME only has 2 Sampling.Years worth of data there should only be 2 plots in the jpg but this code produces 4... it's obviously wrong but I don't know how to fix it. THanks in advance.

```
'data.frame':   521 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ STATION      : chr  "1240062" "125013A" "122013A" "126001A" ...
 $ SITENAME     : chr  "Oconnell River at Caravan Park" "Pioneer River at Dumbleton Weir Headwater" "Proserpine River at Glen Isla" "Sandy Creek at Homebush" ...
 $ Sampling.Year: chr  "2016-2017" "2018-2019" "2018-2019" "2018-2019" ...
 $ DATE         : Date, format: "2017-02-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-02-01" ...
 $ Daily.Ave.PAF: num  24.344 15.226 45.529 44.936 0.208 ...
 $ Site.Year    : chr  "Oconnell River at Caravan Park_2016-2017" "Pioneer River at Dumbleton Weir Headwater_2018-2019" "Proserpine River at Glen Isla_2018-2019" "Sandy Creek at Homebush_2018-2019" …
```

CODE:

```
for(i in 1:length(dat)){
   png(filename = paste("N:/Projects and project proposals/", dat$SITENAME[i], ".png", sep=""), width = 1500, height = 1000)
   print({pesticidePlot <- ggplot(dat, aes(DATE, Daily.Ave.PAF)) +
     geom_point(aes(colour = Daily.Ave.PAF)) +
     scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("dark green","yellow","orange", "red"), 
                            breaks=c(5,10,20), labels=format(c("5", "10", "20"))) +
     facet_wrap(~Sampling.Year, ncol = 1,scales="free") +
          labs(x = "Month", y = "Total PAF (% affected)") +
     scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%B")) +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))})
   dev.off()
 }
```

Comment: Please subset your data to include 2 or 3 different `SITENAME` and edit the question with the output of `dput(sub_data)` in order for us to have an exact copy of what you have. Like this, though the description is good, we would be forced to make up a dataset ourselves and the odds of you getting an answer drop significantly.

Comment: I agree with Rui. Just glancing at your code I assume you would just have the same plot repeated the number of columns. You probably want ```by(dat, dat[["SITENAME"]], function(DF) {...}``` where ```...``` is more-or-less your original code. As is, the data never changes in your loop.

Comment: Thanks Rui and Cole, sample data added via the link

Comment: CatN, why add data via a link? As @RuiBarradas requested, [edit]ing your question to paste the output of `dput(sub_data)` is the preferred way to share data here. Many (myself included) are loathe to download data from a link

Comment: sorry duckmayr I looked up data sharing on this platform and this was suggested as the easiest option, i'll keep dput(sub_data) in mind for next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code can help you. I have used the data you included (Just define a directory to save the plots):

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
dat <- read.csv('Sample.csv',stringsAsFactors = F)
dat$DATE <- as.Date(dat$DATE,'%d/%m/%Y')
#Create a list
List <- split(dat,dat$SITENAME)
#Function for plots
myplot <- function(x)
{
  pesticidePlot <- ggplot(x, aes(DATE, Daily.Ave.PAF)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Daily.Ave.PAF)) +
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("dark green","yellow","orange", "red"), 
                           breaks=c(5,10,20), labels=format(c("5", "10", "20"))) +
    facet_wrap(~Sampling.Year, ncol = 1,scales="free") +
    labs(x = "Month", y = "Total PAF (% affected)") +
    scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", labels = scales::date_format("%B-%y")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
    ggtitle(unique(x$SITENAME))
  return(pesticidePlot)
}
#Create plots
List2 <- lapply(List,myplot)
#Export
namesvec <- paste0(names(List2),'.png')
mapply(ggsave, List2,filename=namesvec,width = 15,units = 'cm')
```

That code will create next plots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can modify `myplot` if you need a more customized plots.

Comment: oh that's awesome thank you!! it's a nice use of function(x) too! if you cant tell I'm somewhat of a newbie at R. this code breaks it down and I can see exactly what is happening, and I can customise it for another project I'm working on at the same time. Thank you!

Comment: @CatN Great !!! Yeah it is a way to avoid loops by creating functions. I hope this helped in your project!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that will save the plots created in a `lapply` loop. The files are then written in another loop, this time with `mapply`.

In the example below the files are saved in the working directory, change this at will.

```
library(ggplot2)

SITENAME_plot <- function(X){
  ggplot(X, aes(DATE, Daily.Ave.PAF)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Daily.Ave.PAF)) +
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("dark green","yellow","orange", "red"), 
                           breaks=c(5,10,20), labels=format(c("5", "10", "20"))) +
    labs(x = "Month", y = "Total PAF (% affected)") +
    scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", labels = scales::date_format("%B")) +
    facet_wrap(~Sampling.Year, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
}

SITENAME_plot_write <- function(name, g, dir = "N:/Projects and project proposals"){
  flname <- file.path(dir, name)
  flname <- paste0(flname, ".png")
  png(filename = flname, width = 1500, height = 1000)
  print(g)
  dev.off()
  flname
}

dat$DATE <- as.Date(dat$DATE, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

sp <- split(dat, dat$SITENAME)
gg_list <- sapply(sp, SITENAME_plot, simplify = FALSE)
mapply(SITENAME_plot_write, names(gg_list), gg_list, MoreArgs = list(dir = getwd()))

rm(sp)  # final clean-up
```

Comment: oh nice one! thank you so much! I never thought of saving the plot code as a function, that's really clever! And it means I can alter the function for other types of plots :) Splitting the dataframe isn't something I'm familiar with (newbie here) so I'm looking forward to using it for this. thank you!