# how do i combine multiple data sources in ggplot using split and sapply?

Tags: r, ggplot2, split, sapply, mapply

this question is linked to a previous one answered by @Rui Barradas and @Duck, but i need more help. Previous link here:
[how do i vectorise (automate) plot creation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087764/how-do-i-vectorise-automate-plot-creation-in-r)

Basically, I need to combine 3 datasets into one plot with a secondary y axis. All datasets need to be split by SITENAME and will facet wrap by Sampling.Year. I am using split and sapply. Being facet wrap the plots look something like this:

[image]

However, i'm now trying to add the two other data sources into the plots, to look something like this:
[image]

But i am struggling to add the two other data sources and get them to split by SITENAME. Her is my code so far...

Record plot format as a function to be applied to a split list df (ideally 'df' would be added as geom_line with a secondary y axis, and 'FF_start_dates' will be added as a vertical dashed line):

```
SITENAME_plot <- function(AllDates_TPAF){
  ggplot(AllDates_TPAF, aes(DATE, Daily.Ave.PAF)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Risk), size = 3) +
     scale_colour_manual(values=c("Very Low" = "dark green","Low" = "light green", 
                                 "Moderate" = "yellow", "High" = "orange", "Very High" = "red"), drop = FALSE) +
     labs(x = "Month", y = "Total PAF (% affected)") +
            scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", labels = scales::date_format("%B")) +
        facet_wrap(~Sampling.Year, ncol = 1, scales = "free")+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Water level (m)")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15)) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
          axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
    theme_bw() +
    ggtitle(unique(AllDates_TPAF$SITENAME))
}
```

plot write function:

```
SITENAME_plot_write <- function(name, g, dir = "N:/abc/"){
  flname <- file.path(dir, name)
  flname <- paste0(flname, ".jpg")
  png(filename = flname, width = 1500, height = 1000)
  print(g)
  dev.off()
  flname
}
```

Apply function to list split by SITENAME:

```
sp1 <- split(AllDates_TPAF, AllDates_TPAF$SITENAME)
gg_list <- sapply(sp1, SITENAME_plot, simplify = FALSE)
mapply(SITENAME_plot_write, names(gg_list), gg_list, MoreArgs = list(dir = getwd()))
dev.off()
```

I have uploaded samples of all 3 datasets here: [Sample Data](http://www.filedropper.com/sampledata)

Apologies for not using gsub but there was too much data and I couldn't get it to work properly

thanks in advance for any help you can give, even if it is just to point me towards a web tutorial of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try next code. I used the data you shared. Just be careful with names of all datasets. Ideally, the key columns as `DATE` and `Sampling.Year` should be present in all dataframes before making the split. Also some variables as `Risk` was absent so I added an example var with same name. Here the code, I added a function for the plot you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
#Data
df1 <- read_excel('Sample data.xlsx',1)
#Create var
df1$Risk <- c(rep(c("Very Low","Low","Moderate","High","Very High"),67),"Very High")
#Other data
df2 <- read_excel('Sample data.xlsx',2)
df3 <- read_excel('Sample data.xlsx',3)
#Split 1
L1 <- split(df1,df1$SITENAME)
L2 <- split(df2,df2$SITENAME)
L3 <- split(df3,df3$`Site Name`)
#Function to create plots
myplot <- function(x,y,z)
{
  #Merge x and y
  #Check for duplicates and avoid column
  y <- y[!duplicated(paste(y$DATE,y$Sampling.Year)),]
  y$SITENAME <- NULL
  xy <- merge(x,y,by.x = c('Sampling.Year','DATE'),by.y = c('Sampling.Year','DATE'),all.x=T)
  #Format to dates
  xy$DATE <- as.Date(xy$DATE)
  #Scale factor
  scaleFactor <- max(xy$Daily.Ave.PAF) / max(xy$Height)
  #Rename for consistency in names
  names(z)[4] <- 'DATE'
  #Format date
  z$DATE <- as.Date(z$DATE)
  #Plot
  #Plot
  G <- ggplot(xy, aes(DATE, Daily.Ave.PAF)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Risk), size = 3) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("Very Low" = "dark green","Low" = "light green", 
                                 "Moderate" = "yellow", "High" = "orange", "Very High" = "red"), drop = FALSE) +
    scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", labels = scales::date_format("%b %Y")) +
    geom_line(aes(x=DATE,y=Height*scaleFactor))+
    scale_y_continuous(name="Total PAF (% affected)", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="Water level (m)"))+
    labs(x = "Month") +
    geom_vline(data = z,aes(xintercept = DATE),linetype="dashed")+
    facet_wrap(~Sampling.Year, ncol = 1, scales = "free")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15)) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
          axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
    theme_bw() +
    ggtitle(unique(xy$SITENAME))
  return(G)
}
#Create a list of plots
Lplots <- mapply(FUN = myplot,x=L1,y=L2,z=L3,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#Now format names
vnames <- paste0(names(Lplots),'.png')
mapply(ggsave, Lplots,filename = vnames,width = 30,units = 'cm')
```

You will end up with plots like these saved in your dir:

[image]

[image]

Some dashed lines do not appear in plots because they were not present in the data you provided.

Comment: Duck to the rescue again! you are awesome, thank you so much! I am trying it out now.

Comment: @CatN Just be careful with the data, in your samples I found duplicates!

Comment: does it matter that there are more data points for one of the variables (water level = df2 in your code above) than the other one plotted on the x-axis? I keep getting this error message and cant find where in the code to fix it: Warning message:
In mapply(FUN = myplot, x = L1, y = L2, z = L3, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter

Comment: actually, ignore my last comment - I realised what I was doing wrong. Thanks again Duck, this code worked. You saved the day! And I learnt something new :)

Comment: @CatN Great it worked and always a pleasure helping you :)